# Trying to understand the web-based terminal window and ssh in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

First, a background question:

I'm working through a Udemy course for the CCP cert and created an instance.

I go to my instance

Click Connect

That displays the "Connect to instance" page. The tab "EC2 Instance Connect" is selected by default. I click Connect.

I go through that process and see a Linux cli (basically, a browser-based terminal window). WHAT exactly am I logged into at that point? I'm assuming it is not my instance/vm itself, as later on the instructor explains how to ssh into the vm. So, is this Linux box that I connected to the equivalent of a jump server? If not, what the heck is it?  The prompt  is:

ec2-user@ip-x.x.x.x

==================

So, from that Linux box/web-based terminal window I mention above, how is the xxx.pem file copied into it? That's never explained. From what I gather, that .pem file must be on that server to allow me to ssh to my vm (either from that web-based terminal window or from my Windows PC using Putty or SecureCRT).

Finally, can someone explain how I would copy the .pem file to that Linux server I mentioned above?

And if there is a better forum for AWS questions, please let me know. I'm not sure where to post a question like this.

Thanks

Comment: It's SSH.  The full description is "EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)".  The PEM file isn't copied to the instance, rather the public key for a keypair is copied with cloud-init.

Comment: It's not a jump box, you are logged directly into the instance through the web browser. Read up on [EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html) if you want to understand how that works. As for copying a PEM file, they are just text files, you can open it in a text editor and copy it, and then paste it into an editor like `vi` or `emacs` or `nano` in the terminal. However, AWS allows you to select an SSH key which it will copy to the instance when you initially create it.

Answer (score 1):

You're connected to the instance you chose in the EC2 console. You can verify by comparing `ip-x.x.x.x` against the EC2 instance details in the console.

Ordinarily, when you launch an EC2 instance you can supply a keypair and the relevant public key portion is pushed to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the instance at launch time. You can later connect using SSH with the corresponding private key.

In the case of Instance Connect, however, the Instance Connect API pushes a one-time-use SSH public key to the instance metadata where it remains for 60 seconds, allowing you to connect. It's authorized by IAM.

Read more at [Connect to your Linux instance using EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html).

To add a new keypair to an existing EC2 instance, see [Add or replace a key pair for your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-key-pair).

Comment: @Anon
Thanks for that info

@MarkB/@jarmod

Thanks for those links and your info. Makes since now. From watching that video, it seemed he was logging into the instance after he showed the  "web-based terminal window" (which I understand now IS the instance.

Is it correct in referring to the instance as a VM? Is instance just Amazon's terminology?

Comment: AWS uses the term 'instance' for "A copy of an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) running as a virtual server in the AWS Cloud", according to the [glossary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glos-chap.html). Other cloud vendors generally have adopted the same term.

Comment: Thanks jarmond. So, is there any real difference between a VM and an Amazon instance? At the surface, they seem the same to me.

Comment: I guess that depends upon your definition of VM. AWS has physical servers running hypervisors that allow one or more virtual servers to run concurrently on the same hardware. You might view those as VMs but AWS doesn’t use the term VM. Is there something specific that you are trying to understand about EC2 compared to some other virtualization technology?

Comment: Not really a comparison. What you stated (physical servers running hypervisors that allow one or more virtual servers to run concurrently on the same hardware) is what I think of when someone says VM. I took a CompTIA cloud computing exam several years ago and the definition you provided is pretty much what I recall when it comes to defining a VM. Just not quite understanding why Amazon isn't using what I thought was industry-standard terminology (VM vs. instance). Maybe I'm just being anal retentive lol

Comment: AWS is in this for the long haul. They know that over time, technology changes. They drive much of that change and create some of the terminology. They’re generally not using standard terms that mean something specific now but that might constrain them later, especially for something as fundamental as compute. That’s my personal perspective anyway.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.